# Activeldap: add a value to a multivalued attribute in the active directory

Tags: ruby

i have a users and groups in my AD.
ou=users, dc=MLT, dc=local
ou=groups, dc=MLT, dc=local
i want to associate the users with the groups using activeldap.
i do that through adding the users distinguish name (user.dn) to an attribute in the groups called "member" which is multivalued attribute.

you can hier read the description of "member"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/group-objects

This is the Ruby code that I wrote :

```
config = {
  host: 'c',
  base: 'dc= MLT,dc=local',
  bind_dn: ENV['AD_SERVICE_USER'],
  password: ENV['AD_SERVICE_PASSWORD']
}
# Connect to LDAP server
ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection config


class Group < ActiveLdap::Base
  query = {
    dn_attribute: 'cn',
    prefix: 'ou=groups',
    classes: %w[top group]
  }
  ldap_mapping query
end

class User < ActiveLdap::Base
  query = {
    dn_attribute: 'cn',
    prefix: 'ou=users'
  }
  ldap_mapping query
end

# associate "Joe" to the "employee" group
group = Group.find(:first, attribute: 'cn', value: 'employee')
user = User.find(:first, attribute:'cn', value:'Joe')

# I used push to add the new user.dn because "member" should be a list of distinguished names.
group.member.push(user.dn) 
begin
  group.save
rescue ActiveLdap::SaveError
puts 'Could not save group!'
puts new_group.errors.full_messages
end
```

I became this error message:

```
undefined method `push' for #<ActiveLdap::DistinguishedName:0x00007f8d2054cb58>
```

can anyone tell me how can I add more than one value to member ????